# Copying an image to the clipboard from command line

Tags: linux, bash, imagemagick, screenshot, clipboard

I am using ImageMagick to copy a portion of my screen into a temporary file (something.png). I would now like to paste the contents of this file into the clipboard directly from command line.

So far my script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

TMPFILE=$(mktemp)
FORMAT='.PNG'
SCREENSHOT_FILE=${TMPFILE}${FORMAT}

mv "$TMPFILE" "$SCREENSHOT_FILE"
import "$SCREENSHOT_FILE"
cat "$SCREENSHOT_FILE" | parcellite
rm "$SCREENSHOT_FILE"
```

Parcellite works perfectly for command line copying and pasting, but I can’t get it to work with image. I reckon this is not a feature of parcellite. How could I do that then ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/301851/how-to-copy-a-picture-to-clipboard-from-command-line-in-linux

Comment: @kan could you paste the contents for future readers ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [`xclip`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip), especially at `xclip-copyfile` and `xclip-pastefile`.

```
  xclip -i < yourfile.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Like kan commented that qdii wants:
http://superuser.com/questions/301851/how-to-copy-a-picture-to-clipboard-from-command-line-in-linux

#### What the community writes there

---

As found [here][1], the key to paste binary data to a file with `xclip` is to tell what [Media Types][2] you have on clipboard. For PNG you can:

```
xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -o > "`date '+%Y-%m-%d_%T'`.png"
```

Or `image/jpeg` and `.jpg` for JPEG.

So now on my `~/Dropbox/.mybashrc` I add an alias (clipboard2photo) to easly paste to image file (maybe someday [we'll have it on Nautilus](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/687749)).

---

#### My automated solution

```
cat (xout) | xin -t (file --mime-type (xout) | cut -d':' -f2 | tail -c +2)
```

with

```
alias xclip 'xclip -selection clip-board';
alias xin 'xclip -in';
alias xout 'xclip -out';
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this:

```bash
sleep 1; import /tmp/ss.png; xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png </tmp/ss.png
```

It uses `imagemagick` (`import`) and `xclip`. Make sure you have them installed.