# Put image in clipboard from command line

Tags: linux, command-line, clipboard

I found this on SuperUser, to put text onto the clipboard from the command line:

> On Windows, try: echo hello | clip
>
> On Linux, try: echo hello | xclip
>
> On Mac OS X, try: echo hello | pbcopy

Would it be possible to somehow use this same method to put an image on the clipboard?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977748/copying-an-image-to-the-clipboard-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be as simple as:

```
xclip <img_file
```

A more difficult question is whether any another application would be able to use the image in its raw file format. Where would you be looking to paste it?

Comment: I would be pasting it into a program like Evernote or OneNote